# rowdata is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqxgrid

I am struggling to see where I am getting an error of 'rowdata is undefined'? when I run my script and press the delete button. I am using jqxwidgets grid:

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm

If someone could help out new user or how I can troubleshoot in firebug 1.9, I would be grateful. I have included my code for your inspection. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.classic.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/gettheme.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdatetimeinput.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcalendar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxtooltip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/globalization/jquery.global.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // prepare the data
            var source =
            {
                datatype: "json",
                datafields: [
            { name: 'id'},
                    { name: 'type'},
                    { name: 'service'},
                    { name: 'quantity'},
                    { name: 'department'},
                    { name: 'date', type: 'date', format: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'},
                ],
                url: 'data.php',
        updaterow: function (rowid, rowdata) {
            // synchronize with the server - send update command
                    var data = "update=true&type=" + rowdata.type + "&service=" + rowdata.service + "&quantity=" + rowdata.quantity;
            data = data + "&department=" + rowdata.department + "&date=" + rowdata.date;
            data = data + "&id=" + rowdata.id;

            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'data.php',
                data: data,
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                // update command is executed.
                //alert(rowdata);
                }
            });     
                },
        deleterow: function (rowid, rowdata) {
            // synchronize with the server - send update command
                    var data = "delete=true&type=" + rowdata.type + "&service=" + rowdata.service + "&quantity=" + rowdata.quantity;
            data = data + "&department=" + rowdata.department + "&date=" + rowdata.date;
            data = data + "&id=" + rowdata.id;

            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'data.php',
                data: data,
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                // update command is executed.
                //alert(rowid);
                console.log(rowid);
                }
            });     
                }
            };

            var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);


            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
            {
                source: source,
                theme: 'classic',
        width: 900,
        altrows: true,
        pageable: true,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        autoheight: true,
        pagesizeoptions: ['10', '20', '30', '40'],
        editable: true,
        ready: function () {
            var button = $("<input type='button' value='Add' id='myButton'/>");
            button.jqxButton({ height: 20 });
            button.click(function () {
            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('addrow', null, []);

            });
            $(".jqx-grid-pager > div:first").append(button);

            },
        ready: function () {
        //var value = $('#jqxrid').jqxGrid('deleterow', rowid);
            var delbutton = $("<input type='button' value='Delete' id='DelButton'/>");
            delbutton.jqxButton({ height: 20 });
            delbutton.click(function () {
            $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('deleterow', id);

            });
            $(".jqx-grid-pager > div:first").append(delbutton);
        },
                columns: [
          { text: 'id', editable: false, datafield: 'id', width: 100 },
                  { text: 'Type', datafield: 'type', width: 150},
                  { text: 'Service', datafield: 'service', width: 150 },
                  { text: 'Quantity', datafield: 'quantity', width: 180 },
                  { text: 'Department', datafield: 'department', width: 90 },
                  { text: 'Date', datafield: 'date', columntype: 'datetimeinput', cellsformat: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', width: 230, showCalendarButton: false }
              ]
            });        
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class='default'>
    <div id='content'>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var theme = 'classic';
                // Create a jqxDateTimeInput
                $("#jqxWidget").jqxDateTimeInput({ width: '250px', height: '25px', theme: theme, formatString: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'  });
            });
        </script>
        <div id='jqxWidget'>
        </div>
    </div>


   <div id="jqxgrid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to narrow-down your problem to a smaller code example, people are unlikely to try to read and understand your 130 lines of code.

Comment: I thought i had? the 'delete button'. Thanks

Comment: I added some code about the data property too ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are invoking deleterow() without the proper parameters :)

Signature:

```
deleterow: function (rowid, rowdata) {}
```

Invocation:

```
delbutton.click(function () {
    $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('deleterow', id /* Missing argument */ );
});
```

You should add the rowdata as an argument. I don't think this code is to be considered very safe.. (which could be rewritten anyways, skipping the "data = data +", see below ).

```
var data = "delete=true&type=" + rowdata.type + "&service=" + rowdata.service + "&quantity=" + rowdata.quantity;
    data = data + "&department=" + rowdata.department + "&date=" + rowdata.date;
    data = data + "&id=" + rowdata.id;
```

You can obtain the rows as follows (
**You should ask for a confirmation, first!** ):

```
delbutton.click(function () {

    var rows = $('#grid').jqxGrid('getrows'),
        selectedRowIndex = $('#grid').jqxGrid('getselectedrowindex'),
        selectedRow = rows[ selectedRowIndex ];

    if( confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete the row with index '" + selectedRowIndex + "'?") {

        $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('deleterow', selectedRowIndex, selectedRow );
    }
});
```

This would be more readable and usable:

```
var data = [
    "delete=",      "true",
    "&type=",       rowdata.type,
    "&service=",    rowdata.service,
    "&quantity=",   rowdata.quantity,
    "&department=", rowdata.department,
    "&date=",       rowdata.date,
    "&id=",         rowdata.id
].join("");
```

Actually I think the following might make it more complex and less errorprone, but easier to use:

```
// Another solution
var customDataProperties = {
    "delete": "true"
    // ,"another": 2
}

var rowdataProperties = [
    "type",
    "service",
    "quantity",
    "department",
    "date",
    "id"
];

function getData( rowdataObject ) {
    // Add additional 
    var data = [];

    function createParameterSetString( property, value ) {

        return [ "&", property, "=", value ].join("");
    }

    for( var propertyName in customDataProperties ) {
        data.push( createParameterSetString( propertyName, customDataProperties[ propertyName ] ) );
    }

    for( var i = 0, ln = rowdataProperties.length; i < ln; i++ ) {
        var property = rowdataProperties[i];
        data.push( createParameterSetString( property, rowdataObject[ property ] ) );
    }

    if( data.length != 0 ) { data.pop( 0 ); }

    return data.join("");
}
```

As you can see, you can easily extend parameters this way.